# How do I cover my IndustrialCraft cables with Construction Foam?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft

I've been playing a bit of Tekkit recently, and while looking up stuff on the IC wiki, I came across this paragraph [here](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Construction_Foam):

> As of 1.70, CF [Construction Foam] can cover & harden around a placed cable, creating a block that functions as a cable but looks like a CF wall.

Would I like to cover up my ugly cabling with CF? Yes, please. This would also be great for patching up the weak spot in my nuclear reactor containment thing (output cable).

How do I actually do that, though? Placing CF on a cable doesn't work — it just places the CF like a normal block when I click on the cable (i.e., next to it, not covering it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a [CF sprayer](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=CF_Sprayer), just point and fire towards the cable and it will be boxed inside a CF block.

Comment: Oh, I see. Kinda inconvenient/wasteful because the foam just goes all over the place, though.

Comment: @lunboks Use scaffolding to box-in the area first, then use the CF sprayer to fill it. It's more material-efficient than placing single blocks since a single compressed piece creates several sprayed blocks, but only if you don't end up with too many unwanted sprayed blocks.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie So how would I get the scaffolding around the cables? Is there a Scaffold Sprayer for that too or something?

Comment: @lunboks It's a block like any other, but has some special mechanics that make scaffold constructions (especially tall ones) easy to set up and take down. You could use any ol' block—scaffold is just cheap and tears down easier than wood or cobble. Just place them where you don't want the CF blob going. You might have to set up and tear it down as you go to contain the spray, which is why scaffold lends itself well to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the wiring of on the ground first, then with the CF sprayer, aim the crosshair on your HUD to the ground BELOW the wiring. This is best done through creative, as it will revert hardened CF to it's suffocating, foamy state. I did this before, and is more cost efficient, by comparison.